# Why don't objects know their own indexes?

Tags: c#

How can we know the index of an element of a list from the element itself?

For instance, the below code won't work because "s" doesn't have a property called `index`. But is there an easy way to get the index?

I know `IndexOf()` and `Find()` but that is not something I am looking for. Because we already have the element, it should be something like property to show the index, right?

```cs
private List<string> myStr = ......

foreach (string s in myStr)
{
    if (....) 
    {
       return s.index;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: A string is just a string no matter how you use it - as an element of the collection, or as a fileld of a class, or as a stand-alone string. No properties will be attached to the string data type depending on the usage context.

Comment: Suppose there's actually an `Index` property and suppose you remove the element `s` from the list and then you call `s.Index`; what do you expect it to return? The element knows nothing about the list. The list knows stuff about its elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know IndexOf() and Find() but that is not something I am looking for. Because we already have the element, it should be something like property to show the index, right?

I understand why you might think that would be a useful thing for the language to include. But, it simply does not. For any given object type, the instances of that object can exist with or without a collection that may contain it. And in fact, a single instance could be in more than one collection. For example, if I have something like this:

```cs
string[] a1 = { "1", "2", "3" }, a2 = { "2", "3", "4" };
string element = "3";
int i = element.Index;
```

What do you expect the value of `i` to be? Should it be `2` or `1`?

The exact need of an index varies according to how the collection and elements within are used. Often, the collection is small and the need for the index infrequent, and so a linear search of the collection is fine. In other cases, the index is needed only at the same time that the collection is already being iterated for other reasons, and so the index is naturally available.

In scenarios where these don't apply and immediate retrieval of the index is needed, there are other options. For example, you can initialize a dictionary that gives you the index:

```cs
string[] a = { "1", "2", "3" };
Dictionary<string, int> map1 =
    a.Select((s, i) => new { Key = s, Index = i }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Index);
string element = "3";
int i = map1[element];
```

Alternatively, you could use the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or similar strategy to wrap your elements in an object that *does* keep track of its index within a collection.

The bottom line: the C# language does not have a way to produce an index of an element directly from that object itself, and indeed could not in any practical way, given that any element could have two or more indexes, or even no index at all, depending on how many collections it was contained in. In specific scenarios, there are alternatives you can use to produce the same result. Your choice of the alternative will depend on the *specific* aspects of each scenario.